# Apache vhosting ubuntu one named entry serving all urls

Tags: django, apache2

I have 2 URL's and two django webapps to serve. Using the following example configuration, a get request for www.server2.com results in the page for www.server1.com.

Example Incoming URLS: ( verified in apache logs)

www.server1.com

www.server2.com

vhost confs:

*** server1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.server1.com
        ErrorLog /.../apache/error.log

        AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /opt/ef/static/css/$1

<Directory "/.../apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /...f/media/
Alias /static/ /...f/static/

<Directory /.../static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /../media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / /...apache/server.wsgi
```

****server2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.server2.com
        ErrorLog /.../apache/error.log

        AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /opt/ef/static/css/$1

<Directory "/.../apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /...f/media/
Alias /static/ /...f/static/

<Directory /.../static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /../media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / /...apache/server.wsgi
```

Am I matching incorrectly?

Comment: I believe everything else is default configuration, here are overall details:  
 - NameVirtualHost *:80 is in ports.conf 
 - Ubuntu 12.04 server 
 - Django 1.4 
 - Godaddy and Enom DNS cname pointing to EC2 public DNS address 
 - URLS show up correctly in Apache log

Comment: is your `WSGIScriptAlias` is pointing at your different projects?